# ASP.NET - Connecting a drop box to a data source

Tags: asp.net

I've created a SQL server database and it's in the `App_Data` folder.

I created a drop-down menu on a page that I want populate from a table in the database. But when I do 'choose data source' option in Visual Studio it doesn't display the database.

Why is this?

Comment: What if you do everything in the code-behind? setting the DataSource, etc. do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After you click on "Choose Data Source..." and the 'Data Source Configuration Wizard' pops up click on the First DropDown there.
2. Select the "New Data Source" option.
3. Click on the "DataBase" icon. You can optionally add a ID for your new datasource or leave the Default ID.
4. Click the Ok Button. A new window will appear with the connection string configuration.
5. If you already have a connection string to connect to your database select it from this list. Otherwise click on the "New Connection..." Button. Follow the steps to create your connection string, or reply if you need help with this.
6. Continue with the wizard and select where you want the data for the DropDownList from.

Hopefully this is what you needed.
Hanlet

Comment: Having a bit of trouble creating the connection string - I get presented with server name, etc which i don't know how to fill in to get to my database.

Comment: @toli, since you said that your database is on the app_data folder when you click on the "New Connection..." button  and the "Choose Data Source" dialog appears you want to select the "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" (maybe uncheck the 'Always use this selection' checkbox). After doing this click the 'Continue' button. You will then need to choose your file by clicking the 'Browse...' button and locating it in you application's folder. Once you locate it follow the Wizard and that's it. Good luck!

Comment: When i select the database in the app_data it says the file is in use but i do not have it open anywhere - do you know what's wrong?

Comment: I could not tell @toli but try closing Visual Studio and re-opening and see if this helps.

Comment: solved it - just closed the open connection. thanks for your help!